# why I can not use "ipython notebook" command

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I used a ubuntu system on aws . So, it is remote from my local pc. And I tried to use "ipython notebook" command there, but not work. I think I downloaded all the requirements. But why not work. Is that because I used the AWS  remote system?

Thank you!

Comment: I got this error " ipython notebook
Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook
" But I can use ipython command to get into the interface of ipython on ubuntu

Comment: I tried the linux on my mac, which is local for ipython notebook. And it works. It seems it is that "remote" problem for AWS.